# Having trouble linking css and js with HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't link my css and js files to my html file.

The most common problem I've seen with other peoples codes was that their files were not in the same folder but mine are and yet it is still not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>    
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share a working snippet

Comment: Are you sure everything is spelled correctly? Also, please add some screenshots and code to help us better understand what's going on.

Comment: I posted the code with the question but I don't see it now. I will try again. Here.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

Comment: How do i add a screenshot?

Comment: Based on the code you had in your question (I've edited it so it's now visible) - you have two HTML elements. You only need the first one.

Comment: Okay I got rid of the first html as you showed but it's still not working.

Comment: Are you sure the path for css and js file are correct? try to see if you get some errors in your browser console

Comment: Nope, no errors.

Comment: Check the Network tab in the browser developer tools Make sure the URLs are being requested correct and you get the response you expect.

Comment: What is the contents of your CSS and JS files? How would you tell if they were working or not?

Comment: If it were working the background of the page would be a dark grey and the math code I made would be working as it did on the playcode website

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>    
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

I expect your folder structure to be as follows:

```
www/
   index.html
   app.js
   style.css
```

Is that correct?

Your code seems OK but what is the exact issue you face? Both CSS and JS not loading?

FYI the files do not need to be in the same directory. Usually, they are separated into folders to keep things clean:

```
www/
   index.html
   js/app.js
   css/style.css
```

Do you see any errors in your browser console? That could help you find the mistake

Comment: I'm sorry for being a pain here, I'm a complete noob at this but I'm not sure what that - "www/
   index.html
   js/app.js
   css/style.css" is.

Comment: Is there a way for me to post screenshots on here?

Comment: so that we can help you @Serious please answer this question _ Please list everything else that is in the folder with your index.html file

Comment: Also _ you should be able to add a screenshot by editing your question and adding the image there

Comment: Okay so I have a folder called #1, in that folder there are 3 files. a javscript file called 'app', a cascading style sheet file called 'style' and a chrome html document called 'index' . Hope that helps.

Comment: ok thanks _ FYI _ your "folder called #1" & @Peadar's "www" are the same thing exactly _ If you copy the code at the top of this answer and add a closing `</html>` tag to the bottom then you should be 'in business' _

Comment: Hey maik, I added the image by doing this - [1]: https://i.imgur.com/Huero5a.png - as it says but I dont see it

Comment: maik - I did what you suggested by copying the code and adding another closing </html> tag at the bottom but still not working, but thank you anyway.

Comment: try this (~) or (.)  like-
<link href="~/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/app.js"></script>

Comment: just to confirm this. Have you saved your css and js files?

Comment: soothran - Yes I saved it every time I made a change.

Comment: Har devgun - Just tried both of those and still not working but thank you.

Comment: @Serious _ I've gone through all of your images and code and I cannot see any issues at all _ The only 'serious' suggestion I would make is that you don't put a hashtag at the start of a folder name "#1" _ Bear in mind that these symbols are NOT text even if that's what you see on your screen _ they are specialised keystrokes that have multiple purposes _(You may want to consider not using "!!!" in a folder name either) _ Copy all three of your files into a new folder on your desktop then enter the new folder and click on index.html _ see if that works (Give the folder a plain text name)

Comment: It's finally working. I'm not sure exactly what it was, maybe just the folder names as you say. I also saved each file individually which I am not sure I did before (js, css and html). Thank you everyone!! It means alot.

Comment: Yep just realised I didn't save each file before(hence why the js file and css file were 0kb), wow I am so useless. Thank you anyway guys.

Comment: Word to the Wise @Serious _ # & !!! are great for folders like 'my pics' _ but you could run into problems using such folder names for coding because it won't just be you using the folder structure _ you applications will be using it as well _ Good Luck ; )

Comment: Don't worry @Serious, it can happen anyone. Just keep practicing. 

Next time you will automatically check that first :)

Answer (score -2):

try this make the links as simple as possible e.g

and for js use the script tag within your Html and see if it working then you go for the linking

Comment: <body> <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

Comment: Please [don't use answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments) to work around comment reputation restrictions.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what do you mean by using the script tag within the html. Do you mean like this - <!DOCTYPE HTML type="text/javascript" src="app.js">  ??

Comment: No! That is not what the answer meant @Serious _ leave `<!DOCTYTPE HTML>` as it is